# How did South Korea's quarantine enforcement work for people without mobile phones?

Tags: covid-19, south-korea

There're plenty of articles written about how South Korea has helped contain its COVID-19 outbreak. [Example](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/23/world/asia/coronavirus-south-korea-flatten-curve.html).

One paragraph in particular catches my eye:

> People ordered into self-quarantine must download another app, which alerts officials if a patient ventures out of isolation. Fines for violations can reach $2,500.

The same paragraph in [another article](https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/seouls-radical-experiment-in-digital-contact-tracing):

> That person is then put under monitored self-isolation for two weeks, using an app that tracks his phone to insure that he isn’t breaking quarantine.

How would this work for people without mobile phones? Does the state provide these people with a phone? I've not been able to find details anywhere.

Comment: No idea how accurate this is, but this article says that cellphone penetration is 100% with 95% being smart phones. So maybe it’s just not a problem? https://www.sbs.com.au/news/south-korea-leads-growth-in-smartphones

Comment: There's still the 5% that doesn't own a smartphone though - presumably those will not be able to download the app.

Comment: @Allure - I don't think you need 100% mobile phone owners for overall effectiveness (contact tracing is just one technique to containing the virus). There are very few people who do not own a mobile phone at all. Even if some do not own a smart phone they could still receive messages like "you have walked next to someone who might be infected" and the person is more likely to get tested. I think the non-mobile phone owners that are also active (i.e. walking in the streets, public transportation) are few enough not to be a serious infection vector.

Comment: @Allure: who in the population is likely not to own a mobile phone: the very young, the very old and the very poor, among others. The very young are essentially covered by those who take care of them. The very old and the very poor are generally not very mobile, and probably do not have contact with many people.

Comment: I hope you realize that they can leave their phone at home, so that's not the only quarantine enforcement mechanism. Also your q confuses contract tracing with quarantine enforcement.

Comment: There are other ways of contact tracing, like just asking the patient "Where did you go these last days?" and then contacting people at those locations who can provide a list of regular attendants. E.g. you say "at this gym" and the gym owner is asked to notify all members or only those who went later than the patient.

Comment: @Fizz: if I remember correctly, people in quarantine are called twice a day. Police is sent to check people that don't answer. For example, the police visited a girl that didn't answer because she was taking a shower at that time. Source: stories from expat groups on Facebook (I am living in South Korea). In Singapore, people in quarantine were contacted through video calls and asked to show their appartment during the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person to be quarantined must provide the address of the place of residence and the landline telephone number of the place of residence. Subsequently, the person in quarantine can receive hand sanitizers, masks, rice, masks, fruits, food, etc., and receive phone calls from the local government several times a day. Through this, check the health status of the quarantined persons and check whether they have left the residence. If you do not answer the phone, after several repeated attempts, if you do not answer the phone for a certain period of time, we will confirm your visit. Perhaps this periodic currency will also help to keep the quarantine psychological stable.

Comment: I created a meta post to discuss this answer (before it was undeleted): https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4406/19301

Comment: Any idea how this works for people who don't have phones entirely (including landlines)?